# Split Dataframe Dynamically Python

Tags: python, loops, indexing, subset

I'm quite new tp programming in Python and I'm having trouble selecting dynamic subsets out of my data.

My goal is to select and work with two columns that are next to each other. For example: Column 1 and 2, Column 3 and 4 etc.etc.

My code so far is the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import indexed as ix #importieren wir um das Dictionary indexieren zu können
import numpy as np

dfs=pd.read_excel('3Seiten.xlsx', sheet_name=None, delim_whitespace=True)
dfs=ix.IndexedOrderedDict(dfs)

estimates=dfs.values()[0].loc[:, :'Unnamed: 31']

for i in estimates.iloc[:,::2]:
     print((estimates.iloc[:, [i,i+1]]))
```

For exemplary purpose I only do the operation for the first sheet of my ordered Dictionary.

The Error message I get here, is that the indexers are out of bound, which makes sense, because I have checked the results and since some of the column names are integers (e.G. 2018) the operation i+1 just results in a different column name (e.g.2019) and not the next position. 
I have tried changing the names to strings, bute then the operation 'i+1' is also invalid. Love to hear suggestions how to work with this.

Comment: `for first_column, second_column in zip(df.columns[:-1], df.columns[1:]): ...`?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Georgy! I changed the code accordingly and now use .loc instead of .iloc. Ih had to change a bit more but now it is working perfectly! Thank you so much :)